# C# Server-Client Application Advise

Tags: c#, network-programming, client-server, remoting

i want to write a server-client application with C#. Server app must send a message or object to client and after this message must trigger some functions in client app. What class or tech should i use? System.Net TcpClient class or .NET Remoting or other technology? Where should i begin? I am beginner at network programming. Any advise will be helpful. Thanks for reading this question and your answers.

Comment: Is it a thick client, web client? Also, do you want push or pull, your post suggests push.

Comment: i think a exe application. server must push messages to all clients.

Comment: Is it a broadcast i.e. one message goes to multiple clients?

Comment: yes. we can think a broadcast.

Comment: Fast small updates (like price changes) or less frequent more granular ones?

Comment: i want the server must send immediately message like alarms. clients must take message immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are specifically dealing with a publish/subscribe scenario, I would advise using [ZeromMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) (clrzmq + libzmq). ZeroMQ is extremely easy to use and very fast. You'll find plenty of C# examples, corresponding to various scenarios on the ZeroMQ site. Depending on your specific needs, you can combine ZeroMQ and OpenPGM to do pgm (tcp) or epgm (udp) multicasting.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest after my questions in the comments section. It sounds like a topic pub/sub model.

Comment: i just have examined it. zeromq is exactly what i am looking for. it is quite useful and simple for persons like me. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) class. Later you can move to TCP, if you need more reliability. UDP is simplest way to send messages across network.

Answer (score 0):

Try figuring out how [these chat client/server apps](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c#/) work. It Will get you thinking in the right direction.